# Should/can a client use the same port to bind to multiple servers

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

Let's say I have a client who connects over TCP to 1000 different servers on a bunch of hosts. And then I'd like to start up 100 clients on the same host. I normally would run out of ephemeral ports (assigned by the os). My solution is for each client to bind to 1 port when connecting to all 1000 servers (thus only using 100 ports).

My question is - should this be something I just do by default? In other words, in my custom connection layer I've built, should clients automatically reuse the same port to connect to multiple servers (and thus be more scalable), or is there a downside to this approach? I am using Linux.

Update: turns out my solution relies on the availability of `SO_REUSEPORT`. The main use case for `SO_REUSEPORT` is for load-balancing listening sockets where multiple threads/processes are used to manage incoming connections, but I don't see any reason why it can't be used for TCP clients binding to the same port before connecting. [Linux kernel 3.9 now supports this](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/). Using python 3.3.2 and Linux 3.11.0, the following works:

```
from socket import *

s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s1.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
s1.bind(('localhost', 23456))

s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s2.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
s2.bind(('localhost', 23456))
```

as @glglgl suggested would be nice, it fails as late as possible, and if you try to connect to the same remote `(host, port)`, you get an error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I don't see any reason why this can't be used for scalability issues with lots of processes connecting to lots of other processes over TCP, and I would love to hear any comments as to why I **shouldn't** just build into my connection layer clients just re-using the same port by default.

Comment: @EJP pls see my update above - if you have anything advice here, I would be very interested to hear what you think.

Comment: The Linux feature in your edit seems to be aimed at servers, not clients. Do you really need tens of thousands of outbound connections, enough to exhaust the port space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should a client use the same socket to bind to multiple servers by default

No, because a client *cannot* use the same socket to bind to mutiple servers, by default or any other way. Do you mean 'use the same *port?*'

> Let's say I have a client who connects over TCP to 1000 different servers on a bunch of hosts. And then I'd like to start up 100 clients on the same host. I normally would run out of ephemeral ports (assigned by the os).

So in other words you *do* mean 'same port', not 'same socket'.

> My solution is for each client to bind to 1 port when connecting to all 1000 servers (thus only using 100 ports).

But your 'solution' doesn't work. The operating system won't let you reuse the same local port for multiple simultaneous outbound connections.

> My question is - should this be something I just do by default?

You can't do it at all, let alone `by default`.

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work. Given that a TCP connection is defined by `(local IP, local port, remote IP, remote port)`, it should not harm to be able to bind several outgoing sockets to the same local port, as long as I connect to different hosts. (And if I do something unwanted, they could me hurt then, and not prematurely.)

Comment: -1, this is what `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` are all about.

Comment: @glglgl It doesn't work because in the Sockets API, bind() precedes connect(), so the kernel doesn't know that you're going to connect to a different IP address/port when you do the bind(). If there was an atomic bind/connect API the kernel would be able to implement the full TCP specification and allow it. But there isn't, so it can't.

Comment: @EJP Yes I meant use the same port, not socket--obviously each connection needs its own socket. I fixed the question.

Comment: @EJP could you please provide some references, afaik `SO_REUSEADDR` also works for `connect`, `SO_REUSEPORT` should work for both UDP and TCP but support varies per OS afaik.

Comment: @KillianDS Don't have a page number handy but it is all in Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated.*

Comment: @EJP It *could* have been implemented in that way that the `bind()` succeeds, but `connect()` fails if the combination is not possible. IOW, fail as late as possible iff there is still the possibility that it could succeed. Alas, it hasn't been.

Comment: @glglgl Not unless you also extended the same logic to listen(), which can also follow a bind().

Comment: @EJP That should have been feasible.

Comment: Suggested improvement: "A client cannot use the same socket to bind to mutiple servers, by default or any other way, but I think you meant port," could have replaced the first four paragraphs (including blockquotes) of your answer. The result would have been more concise, and would reduce the risk of someone interpreting your answer as condescending.